# error: expected function body after function declarator

Tags: c++

I am trying to rewrite some code to run a neopixel strip. I keep getting the error error: expected function body after function declarator   for(int i=0; i<3; i++){ and I am not quite sure how to fix it. Can anyone help me get passed this hurdle and make this code work?  I have tried to google and rework it, but that just resulted in more errors that popped up and I definitely wasnt sure how to correct them. If you couldnt tell, I am newer at this and am trying to learn. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#define NUM_LEDS 64
#include "FastLED.h"
#define DATA_PIN 1
#define FORWARD 0
#define BACKWARD 1
#define SLOW 250
#define MEDIUM 50
#define FAST 5


CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

boolean direction = FORWARD;

void setup()
{ FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));

}

void loop()


  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    CRGB c1 = randomColor();
    CRGB c2 = randomColor();
    stripes(c1,c2,5);
    delay(2000);
    stripes(c2,c1,5);
    delay(2000);



    rainbow(0,NULL);
delay(3000);
  colorWipe(CRGB::Black,FORWARD,FAST);
  delay(3000);
    void colorWipe(CRGB c, int speed, int direction);
void  for(int i=0; i<NUM_LEDS; i++){
    if(direction == FORWARD){
      leds[i] = c;
    }
    else{
      leds[NUM_LEDS-1-i] = c;
    }
    FastLED.show();
    delay(speed);
    void rainbow(int cycles, int speed){ 
  if(cycles == 0){
    for(int i=0; i< NUM_LEDS; i++) {
      leds[i] = Wheel(((i * 256 / NUM_LEDS)) & 255);
    }
    FastLED.show();
  }
  else{
    for(int j=0; j<256*cycles; j++) {
      for(int i=0; i< NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        leds[i] = Wheel(((i * 256 / NUM_LEDS) + j) & 255);
      }
      FastLED.show();
      delay(speed);void stripes(CRGB c1, CRGB c2, int width){
  for(int i=0; i<NUM_LEDS; i++){
    if(i % (width * 2) < width){
      leds[i] = c1;
    }
    else{
      leds[i] = c2;
    } 
  }
  FastLED.show();

  CRGB Wheel(byte WheelPos) {
  if(WheelPos < 85) {
    return CRGB(WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3, 0);
  } 
  else if(WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    return CRGB(255 - WheelPos * 3, 0, WheelPos * 3);
  } 
  else {
    WheelPos -= 170;
    return CRGB(0, WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3);
  }
}

CRGB randomColor(){
  return Wheel(random(256)); 
}
```

Comment: After the function head `void loop()` a `{` should follow to introduce the function body. I assume that this is merely a typo. However there are other issues. For example `void` before `for` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is reasonably clear about the problem.

> `expected function body after function declarator for(int i=0; i<3; i++){`

This is saying that the line before `for(int i=0; i<3; i++){` is a function declaration. That would be accurate since the line before that is `void loop()`, which declares the function `loop`.

The error message also says that a function body was expected next. That is also accurate. Outside a class definition, the first non-space character after a function declaration needs to be either a semicolon (indicating that the function body is elsewhere) or an opening curly brace (indicating the start of the function body). Your code has neither.

So give the compiler what it wants: a function body for `void loop()`. That is, change the blank line immediately after `void loop()` to

```
{
```

(Then make sure all of your braces are balanced.)